# Replace or append row on edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets in a google spreadsheet where sheet2 needs to be updated on Edit when sheet1 is edited.

If Column A in Sheet1 is unchanged and Columns C or D are updated,
the row in sheet 2 should be updated (the raw should be replaced with the last updated data)

If column A in Sheet1 is changed then a new row should be appended.

Could you please advise how the code would look like in google script onEdit?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet2" && e.range.columnStart > 2 && e.range.columnStart < 5) {
    let ush = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    ush.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).setValue(e.value);
  }
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet2" && e.range.columnStart == 1) {
    let ush = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    ush.appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]);
  }
}
```

Please note you cannot run this from the script editor unless you provide the event object.

Comment: The code works. Thanks a lot!